# SQL Case expression in Join clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, case

I have 2 tables as follows

table1

```
id    |      date
------+---------------------
 1    |     1/12/2017
 1    |     3/12/2017
 1    |     10/2/2018     
 1    |     10/4/2018
 2    |     1/7/2018
 2    |     12/9/2018 
 2    |     13/9/2018
 2    |     1/10/2018
```

table2

```
id    |      date1     |      date2   |  value
------+----------------+--------------+----------
 1    |     1/1/2018   |    1/1/2018  |    1
 1    |     15/2/2018  |    1/1/2018  |    4    
 1    |     10/4/2018  |    15/2/2018 |    7
 2    |     1/7/2018   |    1/7/2018  |    5
 2    |     13/9/2018  |    1/7/2018  |    2
 2    |     1/10/2018  |    13/9/2018 |    14
```

I want to add the value column to table 1, matching by id, and if the date is between date1 and date 2. However, in the case of date1 = date2, the condition should be the date being on or before date1

The results should be

```
id    |      date       |  value
------+-----------------+---
 1    |     1/12/2017   |    1
 1    |     3/12/2017   |    1
 1    |     10/2/2018   |    4    
 1    |     10/4/2018   |    7
 2    |     1/7/2018    |    5
 2    |     12/9/2018   |    2
 2    |     13/9/2018   |    2
 2    |     1/10/2018   |    14
```

I tried the following SQL query

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.date, table2.value
  FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id AND 
  CASE 
    WHEN table2.date1 = table2.date2 THEN table1.date <= table2.date
    ELSE table1.date BETWEEN table2.date2 AND table2.date1 );
```

AND

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.date, table2.value
  FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id) WHERE 
  CASE 
    WHEN table2.date1 = table2.date2 THEN table1.date <= table2.date
    ELSE table1.date BETWEEN table2.date2 AND table2.date1;
```

however this does not give the result I need. Where am I making the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.date, table2.value
  FROM table1 
  JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
where  (table2.date1=table2.date2 and table1.date<=table2.date1)
or ( table1.date BETWEEN table2.date2 AND table2.date1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `case` for this.  Just boolean conditions and these can all go in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date, t2.value
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2.id AND
        ((t2.date1 < t2.date2 AND
          t1.date BETWEEN t2.date1 AND t2.date2)
         ) OR
         (t2.date1 = t2.date2 AND
          t1.date <= t2.date1
         ) 
        );
```

You can also simplify this.  One method is:

```
     ON t1.id = t2.id AND
        t1.date <= date2 AND
        (t2.date1 = t2.date2 OR
         t1.date >= t2.date1
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way-

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Value = B.Value
FROM TABLE1 A 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.Date BETWEEN B.Date1 AND B.DATE2
```

Then try with this-

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Value = B.Value
FROM TABLE1 A 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND (A.Date >= B.Date1 AND A.Date <= B.DATE2)
```

Comment: The problem with this is, it does not capture when B.Date1 = B.Date2, the condition has to be A.Date <= B.Date1

Comment: Can you please try with the new one?

Comment: Thank you, but I think I was not clear. I modified the dataset, please check the 1st row, where when the 2 dates in table 2 are the same, the date in the table 1 can be before the table2.date1

Comment: You have Date2 less Then Date1, then how you calculate Date between Date1 and Date? And what if  "1|10/4/2018" combination matched with 2 records in table2?

Comment: If table2.date2 < table2.date1, then table1.date should be between those dates. If table2.date2 = table2.date1, then table1.date <= table2.date1. As of to your other question, I have added more rows to explain the scenario